# Show that the set of of functions that are neither even nor odd is not meager

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, baire-category

Let $X = C([-1,1])$ with the usual norm $\lVert f \rVert_{\infty} = \sup_{t \in [-1,1]} |f(t)|$. Suppose $N = \{ f \in X : f \, \, \text{is neither even nor odd} \}$. Show that $N$ is not meager.

I've shown that the set of even functions and odd functions on $X$ is meager. So I think that the set of neither even nor odd functions should not be meager. I'm trying to show this by showing that $N$ is closed and showing that the closure of $N$ is not empty. I'm not making any progress so I don't know if this is correct.

Comment: I was having trouble with this too. But I believe I showed that $N$ IS meager by using the fact that $N$ is just the union of $A_+$ and $A_-$ the sets of even and odd functions respectively, and that the union of countably many meager sets is meager. Does this seem right?

Comment: @FofX I don’t know if the union works. Intuitively, since the set of even and odd functions are meager, i.e., in some sense “small,” I thought that the set of neither even nor odd functions would have to be large, i.e., dense. So I don’t think that it should be meager. Maybe that’s wrong though, not too sure.